# Getting multiple checkbox value in an text area using jQuery in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to get multiple check box values in one text area using jQuery:

```js
// My script:

$(documnet).ready(function()
{
    $('.chkcmedical').click(function()
    {
        var text = "";
        $('.chkcmedical:checked').each(function()
        {
            text+=$(this).val()+","
        });
        text=text.substring(0,text.length-1);
        $('#medicalvalue').val(text);

    });
});

$(".demo").click(function(){
     $(this).hide(200);
});
```

```html
<!-- My checkboxes: -->

<div class="row">
    <h3 class="mb-3">Have you Suffered from any of the following
        conditions?</h3>
    <div class="form-check col-3">
        <input class="chkcmedical" name="medical" id="medical"
            type="checkbox" value="Asthma"
            style="margin-left: -12px; margin-right: 10px;">

        <label class="form-check-label" for="medical">
            Asthma
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check col-3">
        <input class="chkcmedical" name="medical" id="medical"
            type="checkbox" value="Heart Disease" id="flexCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
            Heart Disease
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check col-3">
        <input class="chkcmedical" type="checkbox" value="Diabetes"
            id="flexCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
            Diabetes
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- My text area: -->

<div class="form-group p-5 pb-2">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Any other conditions,
        operations or hospital admission details.<span
            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <textarea class="form-control mt-3" id="medicalvalue"
        rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<!-- Script: -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Whenever I click on any checkbox, it doesn't show their value in the text area.

I tried to do this using jQuery which I have shown above.

Comment: Hi, spelling for `$(documnet)` is wrong it should be `$(document)` .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a typo.